# User can only edit and view records containing their email in MS Access 2013 database

Tags: database, ms-access, database-design, vba

I currently have an Access database with a main table containing user records, with a primary key being their email. Other records pertaining to that user are held in secondary tables linked with their email. Currently I have a front-end setup for data entry, but this allows anyone access to see and edit all records.

I'd like to make a log in form that requires their email and ID number to log in (both of which are fields in the main table). After logging in, I'd like the database to restrict the user to only see and edit their record and and the records in secondary tables linked to their email. Is this feasible with MS Access?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You need to create a login forms (there are a lot of examples in the internet for login forms). Set this form to your start form in the Access database and make it a dialog. Then let the user enter their E-Mail and ID number. After he hits the login button you can make something like this (to check for an existing E-Mail adress or ID):

```
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("TableWithEMailAdresses", dbOpenSnapshot)

rs.FindFirst "EMailAdressColumn = '" & Me!EMailTextboxInput.Value & "'"

If rs.NoMatch Then    
  Msgbox "No Login for you!"
  'Do stuff
Else
  Msgbox "Login success!"
  'Do other stuff  
End If
```

Sure, you need to adapt the code for your situation.

Comment: SO after inputting your code into my form, ANY number I enter gives me a "Login Success" message. and this code doesn't check for an ID# and the corresponding email address.

Comment: Well you have to adapt the code for your needs. You open a record in your table `Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("YourTableName", dbOpenSnapshot)` and `rs.FindFirst "Column1Name = '" & Me!LoginTextboxName.Value & "'"` (for String) `rs.FindFirst "Column1Name = " & Me!LoginTextboxName.Value`(for integer). You can always debug with F8 and check in the immediate window the value from your login textbox and the value from the recordset.